# Percona MySQL 8.0.25-15 filling up slow log with headers only

Tags: mysql, logging, percona

Has anyone experienced an issue where when the slow log is enabled with the following options:

```
root@(none)> show global variables like "%slow_query%";
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name                     | Value                         |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| slow_query_log                    | ON                            |
| slow_query_log_always_write_time  | 10.000000                     |
| slow_query_log_file               | /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log |
| slow_query_log_use_global_control |                               |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I get a weird issue where the slow log file is being spammed with the same thing over and over again, without a single slow log query:

```
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 8.0.25-15 (Percona Server (GPL), Release '15', Revision 'a558ec2'). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

These three lines are being spammed constantly, about 100 kilobytes per second. Not only that, because of this the replication was lagging, the seconds behind master was constantly creeping up. I was noticing some odd usage of the OS disks (the MySQL datadir is on a different array) where the /var/log/mysql directory resides, I suppose it was flushing to disk each and every one of these useless messages. Once I disabled slow_query_log the SBM started dropping very fast and has no problems keeping up.

Am I hitting a bug with Percona MySQL, I can't find any reference anywhere of this?

Comment: Consider slow_query_log_always_write_time  = 300 to get a reminder in the slow query log every 5 minutes rather than after just 10 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried slow_query_log_always_write_time=0 to turn the feature OFF?

Comment: Please get a SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and post TEXT results as additional information when you are seeing this problem, so we know what is running, please.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding to my.cnf or my.ini the following

```
min_examined_row_limit=1
```

to avoid useless chatter in the Slow Query Log.

Comment: This makes no difference, as I think this is a bug in Percona mysql itself. It keeps spamming the same three lines without any queries many many times a second, like I pasted in the question. I'll try upgrading the Percona version of MySQL.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of first page of TOP from your OS Command Prompt for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have any queries taking longer than 10 seconds?

Probably `long_query_time` is still at the default of 10 (seconds).  This is mostly a uselessly high value; lower it to, say 1.

Is something doing `FLUSH LOGS`?  Check for cron jobs.  Is this on your own site, or some cloud?  They may be causing it.